# WooCommerce Zip Code Pricing per Customer

Tags: woocommerce, price, zipcode

Sorry I don't have any code to show yet as I'm just trying to find a solution.

I'm in need of a way to set the price of products based on the users billing zip code.  I have a custom registration form, I was thinking of somehow figuring this out during that process.  Basically after they fill out their billing info, somehow check their zip code and and apply a price for that customer.

I may be able to write a custom API that would take the zip code and return a price.  But what would I do with this price?  Store it in user_meta?  Then I would have to override $price in a million different templates.

I have googled this and didn't come back with much.

What would the best approach be for this?